# Opening externally created SQLite database on SDCard on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am writing an app that parses a database on a SD card from a camera, and I can't figure out how to get it working on Android, I keep getting "attempt to write a readonly database" exception.  The database isn't readonly and I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in my manifest.

My code snippet:

```
public class DatabaseHelper 
{ 

public static final String  DATABASE_NAME      = "MISC/EREVIEW.DB"; 
 public static final String  SHARE_TABLE         = "Share"; 
 public static final String  PICTURE_TABLE   = "Picture"; 

private SQLiteDatabase      database; 
 private File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

public DatabaseHelper() 
 { 
     try 
     { 
         database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sdDir + 
File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); 
     } 
     catch (SQLiteException ex) 
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "error -- " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
     } 
     finally 
     { 
         DBUtil.safeCloseDataBase(database); 
     } 
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mg.keas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
     <uses-permission android:name="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

     <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".KDEASButtonActivity" >
             <intent-filter >
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

The callstack suggests it's having problems adding a Android metadata table.

```
    12-04 19:51:12.665: I/Database(842): sqlite returned: error code = 8, 
        msg = prepared statement aborts at 37: [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
        android_metadata (locale TEXT)] 
        12-04 19:51:12.665: E/Database(842): CREATE TABLE android_metadata 
        failed 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842): Failed to setLocale() when 
        constructing, closing the database 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842): 
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly 
        database 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java: 
        1967) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java: 
        1835) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java: 
        820) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        com.mg.keas.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:29) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        com.mg.keas.KDEASButtonActivity.onCreate(KDEASButtonActivity.java:28) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 
        1047) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 
        1586) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 
        1638) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at android.app.ActivityThread 
        $H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit 
        $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
        12-04 19:51:12.795: E/Database(842):    at 
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please also post your manifest.

Answer (score 3):

It's a really old post, but unanswered so try to replace

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sdDir + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

with

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sdDir + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Having the flag **SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS** set, you will ignore the creation of the android_metadata table in your database.
This is how I managed to open my databases from the SD CARD.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS works for external database.

Answer (score 0):

If your database file is directly in sdcard, then replace

this

public static final String  DATABASE_NAME      = "MISC/EREVIEW.DB";

with this

public static final String  DATABASE_NAME      = "sdcard/EREVIEW.DB";

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this to manifest as well

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`